# Distributing Dependencies with Application

Tags: c#, c++, build

How do popular desktop applications like Chrome, Firefox, Evernote, etc. distribute or otherwise ensure the presence of dependencies on the machine running their application.

For example, many applications require the presence of the Visual Studio C++ redistributables, how can I guarantee they are present or otherwise direct my user to install them?

Comment: Use an installation application.  There are many around.  Also, redistributables can always be installed in your main program directory instead of the system directory(ies).

Comment: I am currently using NSIS for installation so conceptually I get it but wouldn't it be necessary that the terms and conditions of each dependency allow me to redistribute it for them? Also if you want to do a silent update using something like Omaha, then each dependency would need to support a quiet installer.

Comment: I'm curious about this other solution you propose though. How can redistributables be installed in a main program directory? You mean I take the installation and deploy them as part of my app? So you could see something like C:\Program Files\MyApp\C++Redist, etc.

Comment: `You mean I take the installation and deploy them as part of my app? So you could see something like C:\Program Files\MyApp\C++Redist`  Yes.  As long as your application can find the necessary DLL's, EXE's etc. that's all you need to do.